# PHP oop transfer dynamic array resuls from page to class page

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am making a registration form. This is the second stage of the registration.

At the first stage the user enters their personal data.

The second stage form contains a select input that retrieves values from a table at the db.

I wrote a script with JS, So that the user will be able to select as much values as he would like. I wrote the PHP code in such a way that the results of the form will be formed into an array.

My problem is this:

1. I want to insert the data into MySQL db. the table structure is such:

> #### id | userid | projectid
>
> ```
> 1      1         54
> 2      1         39
> 3      1         92
> ```

1. How do I transfer the array results to the class?
   If i `print_r['project']` after choosing 3 select inputs which their names are 1, 14 and 49   I receive the next output `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 14 [2] => 49 ) 1` which is great! though I don't understand where the `1` at the end comes from

Any assistance would be great.

I wrote the coming code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['regproj'])){
    $sid = $_SESSION['id'];
    echo $sid;

    $_POST['project'];

    $projects = $_POST['project'];
    foreach ($projects as $project) {
        echo $project['name'].'<br />'; 
    }   

    $regprog = new User();
    echo $regprog->Projects($sid);

    echo var_dump($sql);

    //foreach ( $test as $key=>$value ) {
        //$query = "INSERT INTO users-project (userid, project) VALUES ('$value')" ;
        //echo $query;

?>

<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var $project = $('#project1'), count = 1;
        $('#addproject').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var idname = 'project' + (++count);
            var aname = 'project[]'
            var classname ='form-control';
            $project.parent().append($project.clone().attr({id: idname, name: aname, class: classname}));
        });

    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #projects input {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <form role="form" name="regproj" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return(validate());">
          <fieldset>
              <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>                                
          <div id="projects">
               <select type="text" id="project1" name="project[]" class="form-control">
             <?php 
                $Project = new User();
                echo $Project->projectname();
                  ?>
               </select>
          </div>
    </div>
        <input type='button' value='add another research' class="btn btn-info" id='addproject'>
        <input type="submit" name="regproj" value="finished" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" />  

          </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the class I wrote:

```
public function Projects ($sid){
    foreach ( $_POST['projectid'] as $key=>$value ) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users-project (userid, projectid) VALUES ('$sid', '$value')" ;
    }
    echo var_dump($query);
    try {
        $query = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

        return $query->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but 1) I don't see any input with `name` **projectid**, if this is from the select box, you should be doing `$_POST['project']` and if you need to select multiple elements you should have `multiple=true`. 2) Your `foreach` is overwriting the `$query` variable each time, you probably want to put the `try` block inside the `foreach` but the `return` after the `foreach` ends.

Answer (score 0):

o.k, my question was how to add the array output from $_POST['project'] to the method at the user class.

what i didn't know was that you can send a $_POST value to a method while calling it

as you will see at the next example

```
$projects = $_POST['project'];
foreach ($projects as $project){
     echo $project['name'].'<br />';    
}   
$data_count = count($_POST['project']);

for ($i=0; $i<$data_count; $i++) {
$projectid = $_POST['project'][$i]; 

}
$regprog = new User();
echo $regprog-> InsertProjects($sid, $_POST["project"]);
```

`

```
 public function InsertProjects ($sid, $projectid){
foreach ($projectid as $value) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO usersproject (userid, projectid) VALUES ($sid, $value)" ;           
            try {
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
     $query->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    return $e;
    }
 }
 }
```

as you can see the $_POST['projects'] at the last line of the top box code combines $projectid at the Table method and sent it its values.